# How to build a conditional SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a little unsure of how to build the following query for a MySQL database.

My table has two int fields, `startDate` and `endDate` that hold UNIX timestamps. `endDate` can be `NULL` which implies no ending date.

I want to get all records for which the current timestamp falls within the range.

In the case that `endDate` has a value, I can do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE startDate < NOW() AND endDate > NOW()`

and in the case that `endDate` is NULL, I can do:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE`startDate`< NOW()`

My question is, how I can combine the above two queries into one, single conditional query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE startDate < NOW() AND
                          (endDate IS NULL OR endDate > NOW())
```

Comment: Not sure about the `&&` and `||` - do they work cross-platform? I'd tend to recommend just using `AND` and `OR`, imo.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE startDate < NOW() AND (endDate IS NULL OR endDate > NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks. Easier than I was thinking it would be.